# Wrong computation of a series with `FactorialPower`?

Tags: summation

I wanted to compute the series defined by

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}k x^\underline k$$

where $x^\underline k:=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(x-j)$ is a falling factorial. Thus I write

```
Sum[(-1)^(k + 1)/k FactorialPower[x, k], {k, 1, Infinity}]
```

but *Mathematica* says (without more explanation) that "the series does not converges". Thus I thought that this can be certainly true for some values of $x$ so I tried to compute this time

```
Sum[(-1)^(k + 1)/k FactorialPower[2, k], {k, 1, Infinity}]
```

what is a finite sum because `FactorialPower[2,k]` is zero when $k>2$. However *Mathematica* also said that "the series doe not converges". So, what is going on? This is a bug or there is some technicality that Im not seeing?

Comment: Replacing `Sum` by  `Table` such as in `Table[(-1)^(k + 1)/k FactorialPower[2, k], {k, 1, 1000}]` is rather convincing that the series converges... Presumably, MMA does not detect that `FactorialPower` should simplify.

Comment: If you define manually `factpow[x_, k_] := Product[(x - j), {j, 0, k - 1}]`, `factpow[x, k]` simplifies to `(1 - k + x) Pochhammer[2 - k + x, -1 + k]`, but still the sum does not converge.

Comment: `NSum[(-1)^(k + 1)/k *FactorialPower[2, k], {k, 1, Infinity}]` returns `ComplexInfinity`...

Comment: Do you not want to restrict $x$ to integers?

Comment: If $x\ge 1$ and $x$ is an integer, why not replace $\infty$ with $x$ ?  I know that doesn't explain why using $\infty$ doesn't work but it does give an answer.

Comment: sorry, my fault, I did notice that the series doesnt converges for any $x\not in\Bbb N$. Anyway it is strange that *Mathematica* doesnt compute correctly it when $x\in\Bbb N$.